# minimum spring version compatible with java8

Tags: spring, java-8

I have to migrate a project from java 7 to Java 8 and I ran into some of the issue which are related to Spring. I
I am wondering which minimal version of spring is compatible with Java 8.

Note : spring 4.x supports 8 but due to multiple source code change issues I can not upgrade spring to 4.x

Thanks in Advance

Answer (score 0):

From a [blog](https://spring.io/blog/2015/04/03/how-spring-achieves-compatibility-with-java-6-7-and-8) on Spring's website:

> As of Spring Framework 4.0, Java 8 is supported as a first-class citizen

So 4.x is the lowest version that supports Java 8.